# JS - Group blobs of the same colour based on distance

Tags: javascript, arrays, cluster-analysis

I have an array of all the `[x, y]` values for each white pixel in an image. I am wanting to basically group these pixels into separate arrays if some of the white pixels are disconnected and part of a different group than the others.

In other words, imagine a red image with one white blob to the left and another white blob to the right (separated by some distance and not connected by any white pixels).

I am wanting to split the original array of all white pixels into two arrays, one representing the white pixels for the first blob and one representing the white pixels for the second. This is just an example, there could be one large blob of white or many smaller blobs of white - it needs to be able to work with all case scenarios.

My first thought was to use `DBSCAN` as part of https://github.com/uhho/density-clustering to identify separate "blobs" or "clusters", but unfortunately this doesn't work as my image can be large and there could be upwards of 100,000 pixels that need clustering (I need this operation to run in a matter of a few ms).

Is there some other way to approach this or use a faster clustering algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Clustering is the wrong tool here - it is too complex (and thus expensive).

What you are looking for is known as *connected components*. DBSCAN is based on connected components, but does more than you need.

Comment: Ok - do you know of any implementations of connected components in javascript? Also I'm not simply trying to see if the blobs are connected - I'm trying to see if they are separated by a distance of at least `n` at all points. In other words if blob is concave and at some point it comes very close to the other blob (as determined by `n`) then they shouldn't be considered as two blobs, but rather as one.

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic questions here. Plus I would never use a library for that, but instead implement it directly on the problem, so it is fast and customizable. It's not something hard where you would need a library for. In fact, a library probably means you have to spend more effort to convert data from model A to model B and back than it would take you to just implement the algorithm yourself.

Comment: Ok sure that makes sense. Again though, is classifying the "blobs" or "components" as unique based on distance a separate problem? I can only think of comparing all outer edge points to all other outer edge points by euclidean distance once the blobs are separated but I would imagine that is very inefficient.